# Windows 10 Creators Update - Random hangs/freezes

Tags: windows-10, freeze, wpa, windows-10-v1703

I upgraded my 6700K/GTX 1070 laptop to the Creators Update. All went fine...

But... every now and then (1-2hr) my system will hang for about 30-40 seconds and then returns to normal. No input or display refreshes happen until the freeze concludes. After the freeze, the system "catches up" with itself and uses the input that was previously ignored.

I tried a repair install with no luck.

Here's is a link to my WPA report: 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4qr85xf84t2lqe/myTrace.zip?dl=0

Comment: What are you doing when these "hangs" occur?

Comment: @Mokubai Anything, can be just moving the mouse around.

Comment: I have started experiencing the same issues. I have a SSD as the main boot drive and two additional normal HDDs - one of which I use for my windows swap drive. I'm suspecting the latter is the issue and will try changing it to be on the SSD alone (although I dislike this setting since it over-uses my SDD). @magicandre1981 Does this sound like your setup at all? I'll note that setting my power profile to be Performance made no difference.

Comment: @Daniel press CAPS lock key during the freeze and look if the LED on keyboard toggles or not. if yes, you have a software freeze. if the status led doesn't toggle you habe a HW based freeze.

Comment: If Windows hangs or Crashes with the new Creator updates, I have experienced Cortana trying to bring the Desktop session to where it was pre-crash. It was extremely frustrating.  The new windows is doing a lot more behind the scenes and it is hampering perf on my older laptops.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely similar to an issue that was rampant after the 1607 anniversary update, too. It was especially common among users who have multiple drives; i.e. an SSD for their system files and an HDD for programs, libraries, or general storage.

[This is an article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3114706/windows/microsoft-fixes-windows-10s-anniversary-update-freezing.html) talking about the problem and how it was patched by MS .. but it did not solve the problem for everyone. The article doesn't provide troubleshooting suggestions, it is merely a reference/acknowledgement of the problem. It's possible that whatever was causing the issues for the 1607 version may be the cause for 1703 version.

If this is the reason for your problems, unfortunately the only solutions are A) stop using multiple drives, or B) make sure you set up your drives properly (in terms of what you put onto each drive). Windows seems to get wonky when you its things onto a non-system drive. These 'things' include where you install you programs, where your user profiles are stored, and where you direct your default libraries. The community has little information about how much variation from default is acceptable.

For example, I found success by making sure to install all of my programs on the system drive, instead of installing some/all on a secondary drive. Also, installing to default install directories (i.e. program files, program files (x86)) is important, making sure to not install into a custom path like C:\Apps\, for example. I have found no issues from changing the default library locations (changing from system drive onto secondary). So, moving your Documents, Music, Pictures, etc libraries from C:\ onto a secondary drive shouldn't be a problem. The more things you have to keep on the system drive, the larger the drive needs to be, which presents a problem for SSD users.If your system drive is large enough to accommodate Windows, all of your user profiles (which contain settings in %appdata%), you should be ok.

In short, if having a system and alternate drive is the cause of your issues, the only way I've been able to get around it is to have everything except Libraries on the system drive. (or everything, including libraries, if you have the space)

Comment: This is helpful information.  I started getting random freezes after installing the 1709 Fall Creators Update.  Mostly it happens when I'm playing World of Warcraft, but not exclusively.  The commonality, I think, is that it happens during periods of high disk read activity.  I do have 3 physical disks in my system, and WoW is not on the system disk.

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the trace shows a high CPU usage](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1491725645&rver=6.7.6626.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Fchannel9.msdn.com%2FShows%2FDefrag-Tools%2FDefrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis&id=47159) of a process called [nheqminer.exe](https://github.com/nicehash/nheqminer/releases).

So, stop running the tool if it completely uses all CPU resources and slows down Windows completely.

If you are not aware that you use this tool maybe malware included it.

Comment: The hangs still occur without nheqminer.exe running. @magicandre1981

Comment: when you see the freeze, press CAPS LOCK key and look if the status LED toggles or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Power Profile your system is currently using.

I experienced similar issues to yours while my computer was set to the **Balanced** or **Power Saver** Power Profiles. Changing to the **High Performance** Power Profile resolved the issue for me.

The problem of long pauses and hangs appeared when I was using either the Balanced or Power Saver plan. Balanced is the default as shipped. I tried Power Saver and it didn't fix anything either.

Notes: My problem occurred on a home-built Ryzen 7 build running Win 10 Pro with a dual-boot to Linux. Motherboard was an ASUS prime-x370-pro. UEFI Bios 0515. Video card was at first a NVidia GTX-1050 Titanium GT 4GB; 2nd I tried an older 2G Radeon 460 series. The video cards didn't affect the pauses.

Comment: Your first post was deleted because it was not an actual answer. I recommend you do not post the same answer again without carefully inspecting to see if your answer actually adds to the discussion, which it was determined your previous answer did not. Also, do not sell yourself short. You think you have an answer, so don't start by apologizing for a non-answer for the first 2 paragraphs. Get to the point and get your point across. That is how you write an answer.

Comment: Understood, "music". Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score -2):

From the Windows Menu, go to Settings, then go to System and then go to Notifications and Actions. Turn off "Show Me Tips About Windows".

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the author's question.  If it does can you go into more detail how showing tips about windows is causing the author's problem?